# How can I draw lines in editor between waypoints when creating the waypoints?

Tags: unity, c#

```
public List<Vector3> destinations = new List<Vector3>();
    public int numberOfDestionations;
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public bool loop = false;
    public bool moveBack = false;
    public Text textCounter;

    private Coroutine movementCoroutine;
    private bool pause = false;
    private bool coroutineRunning = false;
    private Vector3 startPosition;
    private int countDestionations;

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDestionations; i++)
        {
            destinations.Add(new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-300, 25), -1f, 0));//25, -1f, 0);
            if(i > 0)
            {
                Gizmos.DrawLine(destinations[i], destinations[i + 1]);
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to use gizmos but getting exception :

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

On line 33 :

```
Gizmos.DrawLine(destinations[i], destinations[i + 1]);
```

I want that while it's creating the vectors draw lines from the current created vector destination and the next one. A line from index 0 to index 1 to index 2 and so on. So when running the game I will see a net of all the lines connected between the vectors destinations.

Comment: Hint: think of what the second point in the line would be when `i = numberOfDestinations - 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this instead. You can still initialize your destinations list in `Start`, but draw it in `OnDrawGizmos`, and make sure your index never reaches the list's current `.Count`.

```
void OnDrawGizmos() {
    // Skip drawing if we don't have at least two points to connect.
    if (destinations == null || destinations.Count < 2)
        return;

    for (int i = 1; i < destinations.Count; i++) {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(destinations[i - 1], destinations[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason it's never going inside the OnDrawGizmos. I used a break point and it's never get to it when running the game.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that. It's called just fine on any `MonoBehaviour` I've ever used this with in the editor. Check your spelling, and that you didn't accidentally nest the function inside another one.

Comment: @DanielJacksonville If it's not working, then it's likely that `destinations` is null or has less than two entries.